# Как прописать поля типа arguments в php storm

Tags: css, phpstorm, sass

Здравствуйте. Компилирую scss в css в готовом проекте, созданном не мною.

Структура, в которой мне необходимо работать: исходные файлы _header.scss, _footer.scss, ... Они находятся по адресу default/scss/layout 
Файл результата один для всех исходных -- styles.css Находится по адресу default/css
Как правильно прописать в Php Storm путь для результата? 
Как я понимаю, это поля "Arguments" и "Output path to refresh" 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите объяснения поподробнее. Впервые работаю с php storm и значения типа $FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css совсем не понятны.
Могут ли отличаться имена исходного файла и файла-результата.
Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в слове "компиляция" только одна "л"

Comment: Etki, уже исправил, спасибо

Comment: romeo, наш разговор перенесен модератором в чат, меня туда не пускают, ответить могу здесь. Разобрался. Одна из причин -- ruby не той версии. Аргументы тоже подправил. Сейчас все работает. Править собираюсь пока что только frontend magento, а там нужен именно compass, насколько я усел понять, разобраться бы с этим побыстрее, чтобы получить результат(буду рад любой информации для начинающего). Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

В поле "Working directory" укажите путь `$FileDir$` (путь к директории, где лежит Ваш scss-файл).
В поле "Arguments" достаточно указать `--update  $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`.
Чтобы понять на что указывают данные плейсхолдеры (к примеру, `$FileDir$`) - нажмите "Insert macros" рядом с полем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои настройки (PHPStorm 8.0.3) для Вашего сценария:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окно выбора тулзы (File Watchers):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Update

**1 способ:** Инлайновый конфиг для compass (все параметры в консоли):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2 способ**: Конфиг в отдельном файле. Кладём в директорию проекта файл config.rb:

```
# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public/assets/css"
sass_dir = "public/assets/sass"
images_dir = "public/assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "public/assets/js"
#sourcemap = true

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :expanded

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
```

Прошу заметить, что пути (`public/assets/...`) в конфиге относительны данного конфигурационного файла.

Далее, в PHPStorm прописываем следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я немного ошибся с формулировкой вопроса. исправил. спасибо заранее

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша Обычно реализуется едина точка входа. К примеру, в директории `default/scss/layout` лежат ваши _header.scss, _footer.scss и т.д. В `default/scss/` размещается та самая точка main.scss с содержимым: 

`@import "layout/header";
@import "layout/footer";`

Comment: romeo, у меня такая точка -- styles.scss (''import "framework";
import "core"), в свою очередь в core имею import "layout/global";
import "layout/header";
import "layout/header-nav";
import "layout/header-search";
@import "layout/header-account";
import "layout/header-cart";
import "layout/footer";, т.е., все то, что нужно. Но как мне связать все это в php storm? Ведь править-то нужно, как я понимаю, header, footer и т.д., а результат должен идти в styles.css Может быть у Вас есть туториал на примете для начинающего, чтобы один раз прописать все для понимания. Спасибо, что откликнулись

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша, я Вам представил рабочий конфиг (см. скрин). Изменяя файлы scss/layout/_header.scss, scss/layout/_footer.scss,...  (примечание: использование underscore-символа "_"  в названии сигнализирует, что данный файл не подлежит компиляции, как отдельно взятый), компилируется единственный scss/styles.scss и, как следствие, изменяется css/styles.css. Проверено. Версия Sass 3.4. К сожалению, не помню есть ли различия в CLI синтаксисе/командах между предыдущими версиями. Это я про `scss --update input.scss:output.css`. Посмотреть: `scss -h` (Linux).

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша Небольшое замечание. Иногда PHPStrom под Linux не отображает изменения в styles.css, хотя те имели место быть. Необходимо свернуть PHPStorm в трей и развернуть. В PHPStorm 7 аналогичная была проблема.

Comment: romeo, вроде все правильно делаю, изменений пока не вижу... открыл мой styles.scss, прописал в arguments --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css, удалил на всякий случай styles.css, пробую править, к примеру, _var.scss. -- Никаких изменений, style.css не появляется. У меня windows 7

Comment: в output path to refresh у меня $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css, может в этом дело?

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша У Вас вообще ничего не происходит? Создаётся ли папка css с файлом styles.css? Ошибки в консоли? Может быть вы не выбрали вашу тулзу SCSS для исполнения (необходимо поставить галочку/чекбокс): http://i.stack.imgur.com/MNl5J.png

Comment: "в output path to refresh у меня $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css"
@ЮрийЛихуша, в данном случае, эта опция не имеет значение. Можете её оставить или убрать/очистить.

Comment: romeo, в ответе на этот вопрос разместил скрин

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша Млин, удалите ответ. У Вас разве нет возможности править свой вопрос. Напишите Update/Обновление, оформив его, как заголовок и ниже добавьте свой скрин. Если по ходу диалога необходимо внести ещё какие-нибудь изменения/уточнения в вопрос, можно прибегнуть к нумерации Update#1  и т.д. По существу: Жмите ОК в редакторе вашей тулзы (SCSS) и за ней будет то самое окно (File Watchers), где необходимо выбрать её чекбоксом.

Comment: romeo, добавил еще скрин. если в одном из файлов -- _var.scss высвечивается ошибка -- unknown function, это может быть причиной?

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша Да. Затем Apply и смотрим, что происходит.

Comment: romeo, ничего не происходит

Comment: romeo, пробую править не хедер или футер, а style.scss, в процессе компиляции ошибка Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IBM866 and UTF-8

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша, уберите все импорты из style.scss и добавьте простой класс `.test { background-color: green;}`. Файл должен быть сохранён в кодировке UTF-8 (в правом нижнем углу). Вот скрин: http://i.stack.imgur.com/V7YCU.png

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша Возможно, данная проблема вызвана из-за того, что путь к вашему проекту/scss-файлу содержит кириллицу (т.е. одна из папок имеет кириллическое название).

Comment: romeo, все четко, файл так и сохранен, удаляю styles.css, делаю правлю styles.scss, styles.css появляется. вернул обратно импорты -- ошибка error _framework.scss (Line 33: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
Load paths:
  )

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша Ок. А если вернуть импорты? Проблему необходимо решать с малого. К примеру, добавьте импорт в style.scss к единственному файлу:  `@import "core/layout/header";` или где он у вас там лежит. Попробуйте изменить последний.

Comment: romeo, он не может найти compass. в строчках "@import "compass";
@import "compass/css3";" ошибка. gem install compass я делал

Comment: compass compile тоже сделал

Comment: х.з. какие еще танцы с бубнами делать...

Comment: @ЮрийЛихуша Уф. Вы определитесь, Вам compass нужен или "чистый" sass. Это тянет на отдельный вопрос. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: romeo, мне сложно ответить на Ваш вопрос. Мне нужно править магазин magento. Открываю scss файлы с помощью php storm.

Comment: Содержимое моего config.rb: `# note: this should never truly be refernced since we are using relative assets
http_path = "/skin/frontend/rwd/default/"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
relative_assets = true

output_style = :expanded
environment = :production`

Comment: romeo, проект в php storm я не создаю, a просто открываю файл styles.scss. Прописал, как в Вашем ответе. сейчас получаю `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - compile`

Comment: romeo, мне кажется я продвинулся вперед. после создания нового file watcher compass scss, после правки styles.scss получаю `You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.` Когда правлю хедеры и футер, ничего не происходит

Comment: romeo, нашел [тему](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419011/compass-you-must-compile-individual-stylesheets-from-the-project-directory), пробую разные варианты путей в своем config.rb. Пока то же самое.

Comment: ранее все делалось не на сервере -- на скопированных magento файлах. пробую подключится непосредственно на сервере -- ошибка You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory исчезла, но ничего не происходит, не компилит css

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23527/discussion-on-answer-by-romeo-----arguments--php-storm).